# jQuery: How to obtain the index of a list element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="imgThumbLi">
        <img src="larry.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="imgThumbLi">
        <img src="curly.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li class="imgThumbLi">
        <img src="moe.jpg"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then I have some jQuery to handle whenever someone hovers their mouse over one of these `<img>` elements:

```
$(".imgThumbLi").live({
    mouseenter:
        function() {
            // Obtain the source of the current image we're hovering over.
            var src = $(this).children('img')[0].src;

            // Now I need to know which <li> the "current" (one we're hovering
            // over) image's parent <li> we're in, as a zero-based  index
            // of the <ul>.
            var currListElementIndex = ????
        }
    }
);
```

So, if the user was hovering over `larry.jpg`, then the value of `currListElementIndex` would be `0`. If they were hovering over `moe.jpg`, then the value would be `2`, etc. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Because of some other constraints, I can't add IDs to the `<li>` elements or do anything else that is that obvious...I need to obtain the `<ul>` somehow (maybe via a *parent* function??) and figure out which index of that `<ul>` I'm in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the live function is applied on the  "li" , you can get its index using $(this).index() .So

`var currListElementIndex = $(this).index()` returns the index

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".imgThumbLi").live({
    mouseenter:
        function() {          
            var item=$(this);
            var src = $(this).children('img')[0].src;
            var currListElementIndex = item.index();
            alert(currListElementIndex);
        }
    }
);
```